# Реально ли так наследоваться?

Tags: c++, наследование, шаблоны-с++

Возможно ли так наследоваться? У меня просто ошибки выскакивают:

```
class Human:public Node<Human>; //Здесь unknown template name 'Node' и expected '{' after base class list

template <class T>
class Node{
private:
    T data;
    QList<Node<T>*> childs;
    QList<Node<T>*> parents;

public:
    Node(){
        qDebug( "Node construct" );
    };
    Node(T* newdata){
        qDebug( "Node construct" );
        data = *newdata;
    };
    T get_data(){ return data; }
    void set_data(T new_data){data=new_data;}
    void add_child(T* child){ childs.push_back(new Node(child));}
    void add_parent(T* parent){parents.push_back(new Node(parent));}

    QList<Node<T>*>* get_childs(){return &childs;}
    QList<Node<T>*>* get_parents(){return &parents;}
    ~Node(){

    }
};

class Human:public Node<Human>{ // А здесь redefinition of 'Human'
private:
    int id;
    Node<Human> *node = new Node<Human>();
    Photo avatar;
    QString firstname;
    QString lastname;
    QString description;
    Gallery gallery;
    QList<Event*> events;
public:
    Human(){}
    Human(QString firstname,QString lastname,QString description):firstname(firstname),lastname(lastname),description(description){};
    QString get_firstname();
    QString get_lastname();
    Photo get_avatar();
    QList<Event *> get_events();
    Gallery get_gallery();
    void change_firstname(QString);
    void change_lastname(QString);
    void change_description(QString);
    void add_child(Human*);
    void add_parent(Human*);
    QList<Node<Human> *> *get_childs();
    QList<Node<Human> *> *get_parents();
};
```

Comment: На вид обычный CRTP. Чем вызван этот вопрос? Код работает или нет?

Comment: @VTT да, не работает

Comment: Если не работает, то вопрос следует закрыть, из-за отсутствия описания проблемы и примера для ее воспроизведения.

Comment: @VTT он говорит что в Node используется тип Human который не определён, что логично, но когда я перед Node'ом прописываю заголовок Human (class Human: public Node<Human>) он ругается

Comment: @VTT секунду, сейчас допишу

Comment: Вопрос на засыпку: какой размер будет у экземпляров класса Human?

Comment: Прямо перед определением `Node` напишите `class Human;` и все...

Comment: @LLENN дурацкий совет однако...

Comment: У вас ошибка в строке `class Human:public Node<Human>;`. Зачем вы ее написали? Зачем вам понадобилось делать это первой строкой?

Comment: @AnT Ну потому что, я хотел чтобы класс Node знал, что есть класс Human, а без неё Node будет писать, что не знает такого класса Human, потому-что шаблонный класс T у меня Human

Comment: Зачем? Где у вас в классе `Node` хоть одно упоминание идентификатора `Human`?

Comment: @AnT ок, если её убрать, то в Node в приватном поле data будет ошибка field has incomplete type 'Human'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас в коде наблюдается циркулярная вложенность пообъектов. Класс `Human` включает в себя `Node<Human>` в качестве базового подобъекта, а `Node<Human>` включает в себя `Human` в качестве подобъекта `data`. Это, разумеется, невозможно.

Как вы тут ни крутитесь, вы будете всегда упираться в попытку объявления объекта неполного типа в контексте, где неполный тип использовать не разрешается, или в невозможность дедукции типа или еще во что-то в этом роде.